# What is the location of vscode extension which is enabled in SSH?

Tags: vscode-remote

I edit an extension in the location "%USERPROFILE%.vscode\extensions". But the changes are not reflected in SSH mode.

Comment: bug: backslash missing after %USERPROFILE%

Answer (score 1):

The extension enabled in ssh is installed on remote.

On my Ubuntu 20.04 remote, the location is `~/.vscode-server`

Comment: For windows?...

Comment: sorry, I don't use ssh to connect windows